# Built a Rails 6 application using ActiveStorage, deployed successfully via dokku, now images are disappearing after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, storage, production

I built a Rails 6 application, but built it not considering production storage.

Right now in `config/development.rb` everything is being stored locally, so I didn't think twice about storage because "it worked on my machine".

```
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

However, not it is deployed in production, after every deploy the images that have been uploaded (both stand alone attached images, `has_one_attached :image`, and also images included in rich text content, `has_rich_text :content` are disappearing after deploys.

I understand that I need to configure both my `config/production.rb` and my `storage.yml` files but I am not sure how to go about this.

My `production.rb` file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "taaalk_edge_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session

  # Devise mailer
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://taaalk.co' }
end
```

My `storage.yml` file looks like this:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# cloudinary:
#   service: Cloudinary
# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the Azure Storage secret (as azure_storage:storage_access_key)
# microsoft:
#   service: AzureStorage
#   storage_account_name: your_account_name
#   storage_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:azure_storage, :storage_access_key) %>
#   container: your_container_name

# mirror:
#   service: Mirror
#   primary: local
#   mirrors: [ amazon, google, microsoft ]
```

While beginning to solve this problem I read the documentation on ActiveStorage properly and saw the following:

> Active Storage uses two tables in your application’s database named
>   active_storage_blobs and active_storage_attachments. After creating a
>   new application (or upgrading your application to Rails 5.2), run
>   bin/rails active_storage:install to generate a migration that creates
>   these tables. Use bin/rails db:migrate to run the migration.

I did not run `bin/rails active_storage:install` at any point while building my application.

I don't know if I need to do that now/it will mess things up if I do.

I am sorry if my question is a bit vague, but if someone could answer that last point directly it would be great and point me in the direction of how to solve my more general questions (sorting out my production.rb file/storage.yml file).

**Edit**

I may have run `bin/rails active_storage:install`. I have the following tables in my `schema.rb`:

```
# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "action_text_rich_texts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "body"
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name"], name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, and It's like it should be. Dokku runs by Docker container, so after every deploy your application is running on "new virtual device"
https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container
you can read about: http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/ or use some cloud storage (e.g. AWS S3)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any good resources to learn about using AWS S3 for storage with a rails app? I'm sure there is lots of info out there, just seeing if you know of one. Also, would I need to serve images using any kind of special 'AWS helper' image tag (e.g. with cloudinary you need to do this - `<%= cl_image_tag photo.key, height: 300, width: 400, crop: :fill %>`). Thank you

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/ here are some pieces of information about S3. And here about setting it u with ActiveStorage: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service

Mind that S3 is only one of possible options for cloud storage. There are many alternatives. Some of them are mentioned in above article.